# matplotlib basemap subplot overlaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, matplotlib-basemap

I was trying to generate subplots of some geo maps using basemap. Here is the section of the code I was working on:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#---Some code to read in the data
# ...

#-----Get a A4 sized landscape figure
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(11.69,8.27), dpi=100)

#----2*3 Subplots-------------
for ii in range(6):
    ax=fig.add_subplot(2,3,ii+1)

    #---Basemap contourf of data
    baseIsofill(var[ii],ax,'local')
    ax.set_title('(a)',loc='left')


#plt.tight_layout()
plt.tight_layout(pad=2.0,h_pad=6.5,w_pad=4.5)
plt.show()
```

Problem is the subplot layouts:

- Without `tight_layout()`, the plots and texts in subplots won't overlap, but they all ended up too small and don't make full use of the figure space (Fig.1).
- With `plt.tight_layout()`, subplots take up most of the available figure space but latitude lables starts to overlap (Fig.2).
- `plt.tight_layout(pad=2.0,h_pad=6.5,w_pad=4.5)` gives the desired result (Fig.3). But the parameters need to be changed when a different subplot layout is used (e.g. 3*2 on landscape A4, Fig.4, too small again).

[image: 2x3 subplots without <code>tight_layout()</code>, too small]
[image: 2x3 subplots with <code>tight_layout()</code>, overlaps]
[image: 2x3 subplots with <code>tight_layout((pad=2.0,h_pad=6.5,w_pad=4.5)</code>, desired result]
[image: 3x2 subplots with same <code>tight_layout(pad=2.0,h_pad=6.5,w_pad=4.5)</code> as in Fig.3, too small again]

In the `BaseIsofill()` function, I scaled down the font size for latitude labels trying to avoid overlaps. The downscaling is a function of the subplot layout (fontsize=7./max(nrows,ncolns)+5). Other than this, no other size-related changes are made inside the function.

If I spend time tuning the padding parameters I could always get a good result, but that would involve some trial and error tests and is not robust. After all, giving a quick and robust fix to the subplot layouts is what `tight_layout` is about. So I wonder has anyone come up with a solution to this?

PS: my matplotlib version is 1.3.1. basemap version is 1.0.7